# JmsI18NBundle - The directory where translations are must be set

Tags: php, symfony, jms

When i run the command

```
php app/console translation:extract en --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing
```

i get the following error:

```
[JMS\TranslationBundle\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
The directory where translations are must be set.
```

this is the bundle configuration:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
default_locale: it
locales: [it, en]
strategy: prefix
cookie:
    enabled: false
```

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by using the `--dir` option to define the directory where your translations are when running your `translation:extract`command.

**[From the documentation,](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage#dumping-translation-messages)**

> For dumping, the bundle provides you with a console command which you
>   can use to update your translation files, or also just to preview all
>   changes that have been made.

*Updating Files:*

```
  php app/console translation:extract de --dir=./src/ --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations
```

Comment: i tried to define the --dir option but it doesn't  work.
I fixed the error specifying the bundle and the domains options

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure but I think you can also set the domain either in your configuration.

Comment: i think both my solution and your solution works, with the difference that with your solution you want to tanslate all the routes and place the routes.en.yml inside the app folder, instead with my solution you can translate a specific bundle and place the routes.en.yml inside it

Answer (score 1):

i had to use the following command

```
php app/console translation:extract en --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --bundle="AcmeFooBundle" --domain="routes"
```